# How to lock/unlock recovery?

Tags: security, recovery-mode

If I lose the phone, someone may find it and try to reset the security pattern via recovery. How can I lock / unlock recovery via terminal?

Comment: You can't lock or unlock recovery via a terminal, or any other way, that would defeat the entire purpose of recovery... But Android has what is called Factory Reset Protection in newer devices (you didn't state what device specifically or Android version) that prevents accessing a device even after a factory reset without knowing the Google account credentials. https://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-protection-what-you-need-know

Comment: @acejavelin This level of protection assumes that one has a Google account, though.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman True... It doesn't accommodate all situations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lock the recovery. That's not recovery is intended.

The only chance to do so is locking bootloader.

However, if the bootloader on your device is not locked when it's out-of-the-box, then it can't be locked. Factory Reset Protection won't have much effect in this case.